# UIProgressView is not displaying custom track image

Tags: ios, uiprogressview

I have been trying to implement a UIProgressView to display the percentage of a users budget that they have used so far. I don't want to use the standard progress bar so have been trying to implement a custom one. I am having issues with the custom track image not being displayed.

Here are the settings for the attributes:

[image]

The 'Track' image is 280x32 and the progress bar is set to 280 for the width and the height is locked to 2.

I also have tried setting the images in code:

```
    budgetProgress.trackImage = UIImage(named: "Track")
    budgetProgress.progressImage = UIImage(named: "Progress")
```

All that is displayed is the standard progress bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is broken in iOS 7.1. There is a radar open on this: http://www.openradar.me/16113307

I wrote a drop-in replacement for `UIProgressView` that supports custom images. You can get it as part of [RZUtils](https://github.com/Raizlabs/RZUtils) (look for `RZProgressView`).